# enumerating a list in a list

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a date with events that happened on the date. I want to enumerate the list of events on the date when i show the calendar.

Also I need to be able to delete an event from the list.

```
def command_add(date, event, calendar):
    if date not in calendar:
        calendar[date] = list()
    calendar[date].append(event)


calendar = {}
command_add("2015-10-29", "Python class", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar)
print(calendar)

def command_show(calendar):
    for (date, event) in calendar:
       print(date, enumerate(event))

command_show(calendar)
```

I thought that this would let me access the secondary list under the date and enumerate it but I get an error.

Example out:

```
command_show(calendar)
    2015-10-20:
        0: stackover flow sign up
    2015-11-01:
        0: stackoverflow post
        1: banned from stack overflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `command_show()` function to this, if you don't use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) then you will *only* get the keys(not both keys and values):

```
def command_show(calendar):
    for (date, event) in calendar.items():
        print(date+':')
        for i in enumerate(event):
            print('    '+str(i[0])+': '+i[1])
```

Output:

```
2015-10-29:
    0: Python class
    1: Change oil in blue car
2015-10-12:
    0: Eye doctor
    1: lunch with sid
```

---

About why am I doing this:

```
for i in enumerate(event):
    print('    '+str(i[0])+': '+i[1])
```

As you can see, I'm using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function here. From the document:

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration.
>   The `__next__()` method of the iterator returned by `enumerate()` returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

So it will return something like `[(0, 'Python class'), (1, 'Eye doctor'), (2, 'lunch with sid')]` if the `evernt` is `['Python class', 'Eye doctor', 'lunch with sid']`.

Now we have `[(0, 'Python class'), (1, 'Eye doctor'), (2, 'lunch with sid')]`, when we use `for` loop on it like `for i in enumerate(event)`, `i` will be `(0, 'Python class')` at the first loop, and `(1, 'Eye doctor')` at the second loop, etc.

And then, if you want to print something like `0: Python class`(there is some spaces in front of the sting), we need manually put the spaces like `'    '+`(`+` can join strings here, for example, `'foo'+'bar'` is `foobar`).

Then, because `i` is a tuple, I'm using [`slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). `i[0]` can get the first element in that tuple, `i[1]` can get the second, etc.

Because `i[0]` is a integer, and we can't just do something like `0 + 'foobar'`(will raise `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`). So we need use `str()` function to covert it to string. And then...maybe you'll understand.

---

Also you can do something like:

```
for num, event in enumerate(event):
    print('    '+str(num), event, sep=': ')
```

More clear? `for num, event in enumerate(event)` will give something like `num = 0, evert = 'Python class'` at the first loop, and...as I said.

About `sep`, you could check [the document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more details.

Comment: hey this worked really well but i just wanted to clarify something for my understanding. when u iterate the for loop thru i in enumerate(event) . how does str(i[0]) and + i[1], the first 1 add's the numbers to enumerate the list (str(i[0]) and the second one i[1] gets all the events i just don't know how that interaction works. because i want to be able to delete something from the list as well so im trying to understand what i would need to access to delete a specifc entry at a given date

Comment: more specifically why did u put a [0] and [1] in brackets what does that do exactly

Comment: this was brilliant thanks for the well thought out reply i appreciate it really helps me understand

Answer (score 4):

`for ... in calendar:` will only loop over the keys in the dictionary. You need to call `.items()` to get both *keys and values*:

```
def command_show(calendar):
    for date, events in calendar.items():
        print(date, enumerate(events))
```

You can also simplify `command_add` by using [`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
def command_add(date, event, calendar):
    calendar.setdefault(date, []).append(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` which which take care of that `if` check for you; and loop through the `calendar.iteritems()` so that you get a tuple of `key,value` on each iteration.

```
from collections import defaultdict

calendar = defaultdict(list)

def command_add(date, event, calendar):
    calendar[date].append(event)

command_add("2015-10-29", "Python class", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar)
print(calendar)

for date, events in calendar.iteritems():
    print(date)
    for event in events:
        print('\t{}'.format(event))
```