# Saving a file or overwriting it if it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def save_calendar(calendar):
'''
Save calendar to 'calendar.txt', overwriting it if it already exists.

The format of calendar.txt is the following:

date_1:description_1\tdescription_2\t...\tdescription_n\n
date_2:description_1\tdescription_2\t...\tdescription_n\n
date_3:description_1\tdescription_2\t...\tdescription_n\n
date_4:description_1\tdescription_2\t...\tdescription_n\n
date_5:description_1\tdescription_2\t...\tdescription_n\n

Example: The following calendar...

    2015-10-20:
        0: Python 
    2015-11-01:
        0: CSC test 2
        1: go out with friends after test

appears in calendar.txt as ...

2015-10-20:Python 
2015-11-01:CSC test 2    go out with friends after test

                        ^^^^ This is a \t, (tab) character.


:param calendar:
:return: True/False, depending on whether the calendar was saved.
'''
```

So for this function would i simply just do this:

```
if not os.path.exists(calendar.txt):
    file(calendar.txt, 'w').close()
```

What i'm not understanding is the return true/false, whether the calender was saved. If i created the text file and simply check if it exists shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Well, the same calendars? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33459213/5299236

Comment: And about your question, the function need *overwriting it if it already exists*, so just `open(calendar.txt, 'w')`? `w` mode will clear the text of a file if there is text in that file.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the part about the w mode you said

Comment: Okay, so possible duplicate of [Why truncate when we open a file in 'w' mode in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562100/why-truncate-when-we-open-a-file-in-w-mode-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply do this.

```
with open('calendar.txt', 'w') as cal: # file would be created if not exists
    try:
        cal.write(yourdata)
    except:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the document of python homepage:
[os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.exists)

The exists(path) function just check if the path argument refers to an existing path or not. In your case, return True if `calendar.txt` is exist, and return False otherwise. The exists() function don't make a new file when it return False.

So your code are OK.